# How to hide the Navigation bar using a system overlay window

Tags: android

**LockScreenReceiver.java**

```
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        //If the screen was just turned on or it just booted up, start your Lock Activity
        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {

            //Create a window manager params
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            //makeFullScreen((Activity) context);

            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);

            myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "touch me");
                    myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            // Add layout to window manager
            wm.addView(myView, params);
        }
    }

}
```

**What i am having:**
 I have output as shown below, which is a view on click of it, its visibility is gone

[image]

---

**What i am trying to do:**
I want to hide the bar that has back,center button when the above view is loaded.

---

### How to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
    lp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    lp.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    int flag =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    mRootView.setSystemUiVisibility(flag);
    mWindowManager.addView(mRootView, getLayoutParams());
```

Don not use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`， this flag will make navigation bar always show. I don't kown why.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` showing the navigation bar. I was searching for hours for this .. (has the very same effect on `PopupWindow`s!)

Comment: SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION ensure that the navigation bar is hidden. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation bar on Android 4.0 and higher using the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag. This snippet hides both the navigation bar and the status bar:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

source: [here](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

Comment: But we cannot resolve `getWindow()` even with the help of context also. Methods work only in case of activity or fragment

Comment: are you getting NullPointerException at getWindow() ?

Comment: I am just getting error in android studio, which is pointing that message

Comment: It should work according to me. Try some suggestions given there. That may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 4.4 KitKat, you can use "immersive" full-screen mode. Here's the detail and some sample codes.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: Why not improve your answer by adding some detail and code sample to it?

Answer (score 0):

try with Immersive mode -SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE flag for setSystemUiVisibility()

Comment: Can you check the code above i posted, Since its not activity or fragment .... how to add `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE ` mode here ?

Comment: if u have used a dynamic receiver then write the class inside activity, register it and call the receiver, the action is caught in onreceive method, here u can finish the existing class and call the same class again with the immersive mode flag set, check link provided by nishith above and try.but actually its not a good pratice to hide it .and this immersive facility is provided from android version 4.4 and above.